# C++ strange pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, pointer-arithmetic

I came across a strange output when I was messing around with pointers in C++. Not quite sure if this will give the same output on other compilers but I have tried for GCC 5.1.0 , 4.8.1 and the results were the same.

```
int main(){
   int a = 10;
   int b = 40;
   int *ptrA = &a;
   cout<<*(ptrA-1);
   int *ptrB = &b;
   return 0;
}
```

What I am doing in this piece of code is trying to access the next variable declared in stack frame. Since stack grows from the top of the virtual memory to the bottom I am subtracting 1 from `ptrA` in order to point it to the next 4 bites where `b` is stored. In this case the output is 40.

The "anomaly" occurs when I remove the line

`int *ptrB = &b;`

In this case the same code outputs 65 (other compilers gave me not the same output as GCC, but after removing this line the output again was different from that of the initial code). 
Now two question arise.

1. How a simple pointer initialization statement **after** `cout<<*(ptrA-1);` can affect the program in this way?
2. Why without writing the line `int *ptrB = &b;` the program is not printing the value of b?

Comment: A line that shouldn't make a difference forces different results? That's a clear sign you have Undefined behaviour in the code.

Comment: Add to you question output of gcc -S for both cases if you want answer

Answer (score 3):

You are invoking udefined behaviour. How this manifests itself in this situation could be determined by looking at the assembly code generated from your code sample (to this end, invoke `g++` with the `-S` option.) But one possibility is that when you don't take the address of `b`, the optimizer optimizes that variable away.

Answer (score 2):

You shall make no assupmption on the stack layout.  What you do is undefined behaviour, so full of surprises.

Adding the definition of an additional local pointer variable affects the layout of the stack.  The compiler can do it at the moment of the declaration, or reserve some space already when preparing stack frame of the function. This explains how the additional line can affect the results.  Of course this is completely implementation dependent.

The standard defines pointer arithmetics only within the same object/array:

> **5.7/4:** For the purposes of these operators [*i.e. addition/substraction*], a pointer to a **nonarray** object behaves the **same as a pointer to the first element of
> an array of length one** with the type of the object as its element
> type.
>
> **5.7/5:** (...)  if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N
> and (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i + n-th and i − n-th elements of the array
> object, **provided they exist**. (...) If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements **of the
> same array object**, or one past the last element of the array object,
> the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior
> is undefined.

You may also be interested in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25454666/3723423) about change of stack layout with different compiling options.