# How does computer allocate two variables and how can we calculate the distance between two variables?

Tags: c++, c, cpu-architecture

I find something interesting when i tried to check the different between two variables (you can see in the code below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
    int a, b;  
    printf("%d", (int)&a - (int)&b);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And for each time, result is 12 . I do not know why the result is 12 and I think the result must be 4 (or -4). My computer is 64-bit, Please explain me.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic on different entities is UB>

Comment: You cannot calculate the distance between two variables that aren't allocated as a part of the same array using standard C++. The result of your code is undefined behaviour.

Comment: *and I think the result must be 4* -- Why do you believe this is the case?

Comment: Just guessing, but the result is 12.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are consecutive int data type variables located at 12 bytes offset in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25442458/5376789)

Comment: _I think the result must be 4_ is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Unless they are array elements of the same array, if not you can't guarantee their memory will be allocated contiguously.

Comment: What compiler did you use? Please mention it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia • the duplicate explains why the assumption is incorrect.

Comment: "I do not know why the result is 12" --> VC canary flags.

Comment: i code and compiler with Visual Studio and I think the duplicate has answered my question. And when i use GCC Compiler, the result is 4. You guys can check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is no way you can say that the result must be `4` simply because you know `sizeof int` is `4` in your case.

There is no standard-compliant, 
portable way of doing what you are looking for(getting the difference between address of two `int` variables not part of any array).

Declaring two `int` vars in two consecutive lines doesn't mean they will be placed in memory consecutively. It might be very much possible that the ordering is different from what you expected it to be. (In this case it is `int a,b` I talk about here). If you want the `int`s to be adjacent in memory, an array (like `int ab[2]`) is the only option that ISO C guarantees will give you that on all implementations.  (On most C implementations, you could also use a `struct`, but that's in theory not fully portable.<sup>2</sup>)

---

As pointed out this code is typecasting the pointer to `int` which invokes implementation defined behavior.  Also note that signed integer overflow is UB, and there is no guarantee that `int` can hold the address in a particular system.  Thus `intptr_t` should be a safe way to avoid UB and get a merely implementation-defined result from subtracting the integer value of addresses of separate objects.

The nice point as mentioned that if we consider that the architecture implements flat addressing (like almost every C implementation in real use) then we can simply cast the pointers to `intptr_t` and subtract it to get the result<sup>1</sup>. But well as it says - standard never constrained this particular memory layout (it doesn't demand the architecture to be like this) -- to be much more robust and applicable to large number of systems. Whatever is said holds true until we consider that an implementation in an architecture **without** a flat address space might have some issues that require it to access elements complicated ways.

<sub>Note: if you run this piece of code with `gcc` with or without different optimization flags (`-O3`,`-O2` etc) you will likely get the desired result of `+4` or `-4`. This must be the compiler specific case which gave you this result. (It most likely not `gcc`).</sub>

---

**Footnotes**

1. To covert an object address to an integer is a 2 stage process: convert to a `void *` first, then to an integer like `intptr_t/uintptr_t`.  To print the difference of two such integers, use `PRIdPTR/PRIuPTR`.  `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are optional types, yet *very commonly* available since C99.  If `intptr_t/uintptr_t` are not available, cast to the widest available type and use its matching specifier.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
// printf("%d", (int)&a - (int)&b);
printf("%" PRIdPTR, (intptr_t)(void*)&a - (intptr_t)(void*)&b);
// or pre-C99
printf("%ld", (long)(void*)&a - (long)(void*)&b);
```

---

2. `struct` layout and type sizes:

   In practice, `struct intpair { int a,b; }   ab;` will also have consecutive `a` and `b` on mainstream implementations, but ISO C allows arbitrary amounts of padding in struct layouts.  It does require that struct members have increasing addresses, though, so the compile can pad but not reorder your structs.  (Or classes in C++; the rules are the same there).

   And thus to minimize padding (for speed / cache space efficiency), it's often a good idea to sort members from largest to smallest, because many types have an alignment requirement equal to their width.  Or to group smaller members in pairs / quads if you want to place them before wider members.  Keep in mind that many real implementations differ between 32 / 64-bit pointers, and / or 32 / 64-bit `long`.  e.g. 64-bit pointers and 32-bit `long` on x86-64 Windows, but 64/64 on x86-64 everything else.  Of course pure ISO C only sets minimum ranges of values that types must be able to represent, and that their minimum `sizeof` is `1`, but most modern CPUs (and mainstream C implementations for them) have settled on 32-bit `int`.

   **Avoid writing code that depends on assumptions like that for correctness**, but it's useful to keep in mind when considering performance.

Comment: @MatteoItalia.: For flat addressing - yes it's right. Then this contsraint even doesn't hold. But standard doesn't ask for it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia.: I guess this is not a *legaleese wrong* answer. I am afraid your intention is not clear. if it is about posting a correct answer - it did. I would appreciate a reply comment if it's not too hard for you.

Comment: Thank you, I think i found the answer.

Comment: @VănHợpBùi.: Apologize for the confusion it caused you earlier- because I didn't notice the casting. That casting is implementation defined. And my earlier point holds given that we don't have the architectural constraint that we mentioned here.

Comment: @coderredoc: no need to get so upset by my comments; I didn't reply because I had other stuff to do. I removed my downvote because it's no longer wrong about the UB bit. Still, I'm not upvoting because IMO it doesn't answer the question, i.e. "why would the compiler place two local 4-byte variables 12 bytes apart on the stack".

Comment: @MatteoItalia.: But I said that the ordering is not necessarily one after another - in this particular case it might be possible that they are placed with intermediate memory bytes in between them. And thanks for the comment. It's great that you helped. Maybe I would learn from you after having this discussion with you here.

Comment: That's what was already evident from the question itself - if they aren't one besides the other, it's clear that there's something in between. Now the question is: given that compilers aren't known to waste stack space, what is in there, and why? Padding to keep the variables aligned? Other locals? Canary flags? If you read the linked duplicate you'll find out that there is a good possibility that the space in between is used for buffer overrun protection. That's an answer from which I actually learned something, not one focusing on why that measurement is technically not guaranteed by C++.

Comment: @MatteoItalia.: I didn't even approach that problem from that viewpoint(noticed the dup)  But have you noticed that the compiler is `MSVC`?  I am not sure what compiler OP used. Maybe I will test a bit with the code using `gcc`. I guess with gcc the behavior will be one expected by OP. And then what compiler did OP use? `conio` is there - any MSDOS compiler?

Comment: @coderredoc: given the `<conio.h>` and the `getch()` at the end to avoid the terminal to close after running it from inside the IDE, my guess is VC++ on Windows. But then of course the only way to be sure is to ask.

Comment: @MatteoItalia.: I have been checking this on `gcc` - well it gives me desired behavior as expected by OP. I guess it is native to VC++ or microsoft prop compilers. This is really odd. But one interesting thing  I found out which claims what I said about ordering. In case I compile with different swicthes for optimization result might be `-4` too . But I don't think `gcc` does that just like non-debug mode of VC++ won't.

Comment: @coderredoc: yep; the most similar thing gcc has is `-fstack-protector-all`, but it doesn't do a thing for variables smaller than 8 bytes, and even in that case IIRC it just checks a canary to detect return address overwrite, it doesn't add stuff between variables in the same stack frame. For more advanced debugging checks it has the address sanitizer, but it works in a completely different way.

Comment: @MatteoItalia.: I already checked with `-fstack-protector-all` - no it doesn;t take that measure. I am afraid it can't be replicated in `gcc`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Canary flags with VC is certainly the reason for 12 vs 4.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Since the standard does not specify the arithmetics for pointers to unrelated objects, subtracting such pointers is prone to UB and it is implementation dependant.

Since it is implementation dependent one cannot count on the results.

Typically, from the experience, complier would allocated two integers on the program stack close (size by side) to each other. In this case for system with flat memory architecture subtracting addresses would give us the size of the `int`.

This is test to check what your program could give you:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {

   int a, b;  

   // Print address of the variables of a and b

   printf("Address of b %p\n", (void *)&b);
   printf("Address of a %p\n", (void *)&a);

   // THIS IS PRONE TO UB since pointers `&a` and '&b' not related to each other: 
   printf("Substructing pointers:  %lld\n",  &b - &a );

   // Now we substract addresses:

   // Get the distance in memory on any architecture with flat addressing.
   printf("\nSubtracting addr:  %lld\n", (long long int)&b - (long long int)&a);
   printf("Subtracting addr:  %lld\n", (__intptr_t)(void *)&b - (__intptr_t)(void *)&a);
   printf("%" PRIdPTR, (intptr_t)(void*)&a - (intptr_t)(void*)&b);       

   return 0;
```

}

Output:

```
Address of b 0x7ffc2d3cd2d4
Address of a 0x7ffc2d3cd2d0
Substructing pointers:  1

Subtracting addr:  4
Subtracting addr:  4
-4
```

Comment: @VănHợpBùi You could test what is behaviour on your  particular system using the program above.

Comment: Using `"%p"` to print a `int *` is UB. Subtracting unrelated pointers is UB. Using `"%d"` to print a `ptrdiff_t` is another layer of UB.  `printf("\nSubtracting addr:  %lld\n", (long int)&b - (long int)&a);` is another UB.  Unclear why code did not cast to `long long` here.  That would have been this answer's best approach.

Comment: @chux Thank you for your comment!. The code has been improved accordingly.